# Drupal State Machines, usage and alternatives

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, workflow

Do "State Machines" used in Workflow-NG module (D5) have any visual interface (in node form or whatever)?
Or they are totally internal entities that I can only set and evaluate?
The initial objective  behind question was to send emails based on changed node status (taxonomy based).

If these State Machines are cumbersome, I can probably refuse from then in favour of custom module tracking node changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "visual interface"?

Comment: E.g. a Label or listbox displaying current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be any kind of UI for them today. However, it shouldn't be too much work to get something like [graphiz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to build them for you.